# Template not found on Rails when I just redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, redirect

I'm making a Rails app where I have a method:

```
def updateAttributes_post
  if logged_in?
    userPlucky = User.where(:screen_name=>session[:screen_name]).all
    userPlucky.each do | user |
      user.update_attributes(:email => params[:emailAddr], :password=>params[:passwordStr])
      if user.save
        flash[:success] = "Succesfully updated attributes!"
        redirect_to '/dashboard'
      else
        errors = Array.new()
        for i in 0..user.errors.full_messages.count
          errors.push(user.errors.full_messages[i])
        end
        session[:error] = errors
        flash[:error] = "Error saving"
        redirect_to '/update'
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

which is called on a POST request. The thing is on every `if` I'm redirecting on both cases, but I'm still getting a Template not found`. If I add a template with the name it asks it just renders the blank template without doing nothing. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no user matches (ie `userPlucky` is empty), you do not call any `redirect_to`.